# Why does my shower turn on when I turn on the hot water in the bathroom sink?

Tags: bathroom

I'm perplexed by this. Why does my shower turn on when I turn on the hot water  in the bathroom sink? I lose water pressure when I turn on the sink, then the shower turns on. Any ideas?

Comment: I would love to know the reason. I had something similar with a tap on my garden which is connected to the same pipe as the kitchen tap. (only once) I opened the tap on the garden ... and water started to come out of the tap on the kitchen.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a washerless faucet issue.

Water pressure holds the plate that seals the unit. As the pressure drops, the handle can move, allowing flow. You may have luck replacing the seals--not very difficult. Turn the water both hot and cold off. With most of these type faucets the top section unscrews. Remove the cartridge take the seals to a home store or hardware store and they will usually have replacements (there are different sizes). Reassemble and see if that fixes the problem.

Other than that, a lighter weight handle may be needed if you cannot tighten it up.