# When tub/shower is on in bathroom #1 a shower other side of house turns on in bathroom #2

Tags: bathroom, water, shower

When the tub/shower in #1 bathroom is running water another shower stall in #2 bathroom turns on.  What is causing this to happen?  How is this fixed?

Comment: How high was the plumber when hooking up the pipes?  Unless the bathrooms/showers share the same wall, it should be next to impossible.

Comment: The house was built way before we purchased it.  So I don't know how high the plumber was when hooking up the pipes.  It is possible, because it is happening. lol  Not sure how, but it is and I am wondering what needs to be fixed for it to stop happening.

Comment: Is #2 that turns on unexpectedly just a small drip, or does it turn on fully?

Comment: If I wanted it to happen, would need just two tees and a length of pipe connecting both shower pipes.  Does it matter which shower is turned on, #1 and #2 turns on,  #2 and #1 turns on?  Will need to access wall where shower pipes go up to shower head, cut and cap pipe going somewhere else.  Should only have one pipe going to shower head.

Comment: This link might point to a different fix, without knowing types of faucets/taps, I am kind of guessing.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/82892/why-does-my-shower-turn-on-when-i-turn-on-the-hot-water-in-the-bathroom-sink?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Washerless faucets are known to have this problem.
When the pressure drops the weight of the handle can pull the valve on.

Opening the valve and making the springs tighter has worked for some.
Heavier springs are required in the worst cases.
I believe we had 1 person that had it fixed until they opened the garden hose (large flow).
Increasing the pressure may help if you have a pressure reducing valve or well pump increasing the pressure for cut in and off.
But heavier springs or a lighter weight handle may be needed to really fix the problem.